# SQL: Grouping by 2 columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table `points`:

```
event_time         | name  | points |
------------------------------------
2014-07-16 11:40     Bob        10
2014-07-16 10:00     Jim        20
2014-07-16 09:20     Jim        30
2014-07-15 11:20     Bob         5
2014-07-15 10:20    Anna        10
2014-07-15 09:40     Bob        30
2014-07-15 09:00    Anna        10
```

Is it possible to make a query that results with:

```
event_date   | name | total_points |
------------------------------------
2014-07-16     Bob            10
2014-07-16     Jim            50
2014-07-15     Bob            35
2014-07-15    Anna            20
```

Where `total_points` is a sum of all points for the given name during the day?

Comment: Yes it is. You can (as your title suggests) group by two columns.

Comment: @maxB: This question is only slightly different from your last one. Did you try solving it before posting here?

Comment: @juergend Yes I did, but with no luck. I am professional in another areas and in sql I am noob - this is why I asked this question.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic, because it asks us to try your suggestion, while you could very well try it yourself first, especially with the answer that was given to your previous, very similar, question.

Comment: I think it would be better for you to try understanding the queries you got provided with. Then you can do them by yourself in the future.

Comment: @juergend I promise I will master my SQL skills.

Comment: @GolezTrol Sorry that I disturbed you. I always knew that there are people that don't like to be asked. So, sorry again that you saw my question.

Comment: I don't mind being asked, but I (and many of my fellow SO volunteers) appreciate if you try yourself first and share your attempts, instead of blatantly asking for a complete piece of code. It's like asking a carpenter to make a chair for free, because you don't know how and you don't feel like buying one.

Comment: @GolezTrol I wish you good evening... please don't be mad on me. please forget my question. I feel so sorry that you so mad on me... I will delete this question if you wish - just say and I will delete it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select date(event_time) as event_date,
       name,
       sum(points) as total_points
from points
group by date(event_time), name
```